# XSL variable to lower case

Tags: xslt

I have an XML feed data that I need to make into a link using XSL v1.0... this works, but the `TYPE` value needs to be in lower case for the link to work properly:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/{TYPE}={ID}" target="_blank">
  <img src="{IMAGE}" />
</a>
```

So, I tried doing this but it's giving me errors and I'm finding it difficult to trouble shoot as the error comes back as "XSLT compile error at (1,991). See InnerException for details." (the below is just a snippet).

```
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://www.mysite.com/', translate(TYPE, $uppercase, $smallcase),'=',ID)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="target">
    <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:text><img src="{IMAGE}" /></xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Is there some blatantly obvious error there that I'm missing? Or maybe an easier method?

Comment: @fidgey: Check my answer for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much cleaner:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/{translate(
                                   TYPE,
                                   $uppercase,
                                   $smallcase)}={ID}"
   target="_blank">
   <img src="{IMAGE}" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:text><img src="{IMAGE}" /></xsl:text>
```

should just be

```
<img src="{IMAGE}" />
```